# Enforce that the accepted Class type has a no arguments constructor

Tags: typescript, types, constructor, higher-order-functions

Given some function with a parameter for a Class (not an object or instance, but the Class itself), or equivalently a variable assigned to a Class.

The problem is to enforce that the Class assigned to the parameter is a Class that has a no argument constructor (only, as classes in JS may have at most one constructor from the spec, section [8.3](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#8.3) ([8.3](https://github.com/teppeis/typescript-spec-md/blob/master/en/ch08.md#83-constructor-declarations))). The use case for this is to design a generic function that can construct (and return) instances of the given class.

Concretely, adding the required type checking for parameter `c`:

```
function acceptsAClassParameter(c) {
    return new c();
}

class MyClassWithNoArgsConstructor { constructor() { ... } }
class MyClassWithArgsConstructor { constructor(foo) { ... } }

acceptsAClassParameter(MyClassWithNoArgsConstructor);
acceptsAClassParameter(MyClassWithArgsConstructor); // type error
```

Answer (score 0):

The [TypeScript documentation for Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics) provides an example of factories referring to class types by their constructor functions:

```
function create<Type>(c: { new (): Type }): Type {
  return new c();
}
```

The key is to use that, and avoid using a signature that would enforce that the constructor accepts no parameters, like: `(...args: never[]) => any`.

For the given example:

```
type NoArgsConstructor<T> = new () => T;
function createInstanceWithNoArgsConstructor<T>(c: NoArgsConstructor<T>) {
    return new c();
}

class MyClassWithNoArgsConstructor { constructor() { ... } }
class MyClassWithArgsConstructor { constructor(foo) { ... } }

createInstanceWithNoArgsConstructor(MyClassWithNoArgsConstructor);
createInstanceWithNoArgsConstructor(MyClassWithArgsConstructor); // Error: Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
```

[TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gQQE4HMDOBhOA7NwkCuAxsHEgDwAqAfFALxTYQDuUAFAJT22UDcAUADMC2EgEscUIkggBDYBACSuYLNEQA6mOAALeMnRYVhEmSrU2RAFyxEqTDjwnSFGlwDe-KN6gzgBJGxGFilOAQBffn4iABtZNDQoAFkQDDiErV19eyMnYhcodylHfHyyTkKoAHoAKgA6BpqqqHCW6PTElLT4tEydAwdjMqRKohLncsE4OBs1EA9q%20sbm1sjomXklFTUiTW09O0Nx4bYujr7so6HTJA4BaTkFZTwdvazDwbyb09Tz-YHcqUbndqs1QJAoBAkEgyPwgA)

Comment: Yep, since functions are contravariant with respect to their parameters. You could give a `new () => T` to something that expects a `new (foo: any) => T`, but not the other way around.